# how to check if all checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have form like this:

[image]

So, if i checked the checkbox and then click edit, it will redirect to editing page and showing the checked data only.

The problems is appear if i didn't check any checkbox and then click edit or delete, it will show error message, probably because no data selected/checked.

So i want my edit and delete button to have some kind of alerts, so if i didn't check any data and then click edit or delete, i want it to show alerts or at least didn't do anything.

Here's my form code:

```
<form name='frmedit' method='post' action=''>
<table>
<tr>
<td>&#10003;</td>
<td>No.</td>
<td>Nama</td>
<td>Merk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' value='$data[id_usulan]' ></td>
      <td>$no.</td>
      <td>$data[nama]</td>
      <td>$data[merk]</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='allbox' value='check' onClick='checkAll(0);'/>Check All
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<input type='button' name='update' value='Edit' onClick='setUpdateAction();'/>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete'  onClick='setDeleteAction();' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The edit and delete function is in onClick, and the function is:

```
function setUpdateAction() {

if($('#frmedit input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
    document.frmedit.action = "edit_user.php";
document.frmedit.submit();
    }else{
alert("Please check at least one.");
return false;
    }
}
```

As for setDeleteAction, i still didn't do anything.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ahh yes, sorry sorry, i'll post what i already tried..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of checking all boxes are unchecked, you can check if anyof them are checked. Like

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){

  if($(".test:checked").length == 0) {
    alert("nothing is checked");
  } else {
    alert("something is checked");
  }
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="5" />

<button>check</button>
```